# Fill textbox based on checkbox choices and prevent doubles

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, textbox

I have the following code to fill a textbox based on checkbox choices on buttonclick.

```
 If ChkOM.Checked Then
    txtOpp.Text += ChkOM.Text & Environment.NewLine
Else
    txtOpp.Text = ""
End If
If ChkHSM.Checked Then
    txtOpp.Text += ChkHSM.Text & Environment.NewLine
Else
    txtOpp.Text = ""
End If
```

This code works to an extend, but when i uncheck and later recheck the box it will fill the textbox with 2x the same text. how do i prevent these doubles?

Comment: Based on what you've told us, the answer is to just clear the `TextBox` first. That's probably not a solution though, but you haven't actually provided the information we'd need to know that. Please provide ALL the relevant information. If there is nothing else then, as I said, just clear the `TextBox`, but I'm not sure why that wouldn't be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this IF statement, and declare the new variables to STATIC.

```
If ChkOM.Checked Then
    If lasttext1 = chkOM.text Then
    Else
        lasttext1 = chkOM.text
        txtOpp.Text += ChkOM.Text & Environment.NewLine
    End if
Else
    txtOpp.Text = ""
End If
```

Repeat for the second textbox too. (lasttext2)